# What is the difference between POJO and DAO

Tags: java, dao, pojo

May I know what is the difference between POJO (Plain old java object) and DAO (Data access object) in Java.

Where to use which one?

From the Jboss hibernate tutorial (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-pojo), why POJO  is used with database if we have DAO?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A POJO is a simple Java object whilst a DAO is a facade to access the database not directly by SQL or similar but by passing objects at it and the DAO has to handle persisting by itself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154202/data-access-object-dao-in-java

Comment: POJO means that your class will have all getters and setters for each attribute. DAO will handle data access and modification. A DAO is able to use POJO object in order to save or get one.

Comment: DAO = Data Access Object. POJO = Plain Old Java Object. If you just look at the full terms you should already see what their general purpose is.

Answer (score 8):

In Java parlance, a DAO is an organizing class that contains methods to access a database table.  A POJO holds database records.  A DAO will return POJOs from some of its methods.

Answer (score 6):

Term is already easy to understand. It is Design pattern. if you agree it, you can use. Otherwise, you cannot.

**As you mention**

POJO is `Plain old java object` which take responsibility to keep the data, not business processing.

DAO is `Data access object` which take responsibility to process persistence/database processing.

Comment: his question is regarding the jboss hibernate tutorial