# java spring boot HTTP POST request not working

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

For my application I am writing a POST request to send array of parameters from a checkbox list. Its working for get request but not working for post request. What is the error in my code.

My code on the client side for sending ajax request to the server.

```
$(".add").click(function(){

    monitoring.length=0;
    nonMonitoring.length=0;
    $('.modal-body input:checked').each(function() {
        monitoring.push($(this).val());
        });

    $('.addkeywords input:checked').each(function() {
        nonMonitoring.push($(this).val());
        });


//  alert(monitoring[2]+ " " + nonMonitoring[2]);
    var monitoringLength=monitoring.length;
    var nonMonitoringLength=nonMonitoring.length;

    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : '/rest/channelstats/my/rest/controller',
            data : {
            //  monitoring : monitoring,
            //  nonMonitoring: nonMonitoring,
                monitoringLength: monitoringLength,
                nonMonitoringLength: nonMonitoringLength,

            },
            success : function(data) {

            //  var keywordsList=data
                //console.log(keywordsList);
            //  htm = "" ;


            }


});


    })
```

My java code on the server side.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/channelstats/my/rest/controller",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void monitorKeywords(@RequestParam(value="monitoringLength",required=true)int monitoringLength,@RequestParam(value="nonMonitoringLength",required=true)int nonMonitoringLength){
    System.out.println("MonitoringLength =>" +monitoringLength);
    System.out.println("NonMonitoringLength=>" +nonMonitoringLength);

}

}
```

Its working for HTTP GET requests but not working for POST requests.How should I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Its not showing any error its not printing the output in the console

Comment: ya in my java console..  I mean in my eclipse console

Comment: Hi, have you ever fixed this problem? I encountered this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

According to your jquery post request, you should use DAO[(Data Access Object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154202/data-access-object-dao-in-java) to parse the request data. So you should add class `Request`

```
public class Request {

    private int monitoringLength;
    private int nonMonitoringLength;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And change controller to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/channelstats/my/rest/controller",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void monitorKeywords(@RequestBody Request request){
    System.out.println("MonitoringLength =>"+request.getMonitoringLength());            
    System.out.println("NonMonitoringLength=>"+request.getNonMonitoringLength());
}
```