# Insert to database using web service in java

Tags: java, web-services

when i wrote function instead of procedure, it compiled.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function ilce_gtr
(
    p_ilkodu number  
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
 p_geridonen varchar2(1000);
begin
for rec in(SELECT ADI FROM ILCE WHERE Y_IL=p_ilkodu)
loop
p_geridonen := p_geridonen || '|' || rec.ADI;
end loop;
return p_geridonen;
end;
/
```

then i created xml via web method, it was successful.

```
 @WebMethod
        public String get_ilce (int p_ilkodu) {

            Statement stmt=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Connection conn=null;
            String deger=null;

            try {
              conn= getConnection_test();
              String query = "SELECT ILCE_GTR('" + p_ilkodu + "') FROM DUAL";
              stmt = conn.createStatement();
              rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
              while (rs.next()) {
               deger = rs.getString(1);                        
              }        

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "hata";
            } finally {
              try {
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                return "hata";
              }          
            }            
            return deger;
        }
```

I want to do the same for inserting to database, can u help me?

Comment: try logging your exceptions rather than `catch (Exception e) {
                return "hata";
            }`

Comment: This code created and it successful but it doesnt insert to database. How can I do the insertion process? Is the stored procedure in database or web method in java? @Scary Wombat

Comment: SQL should be fine e.g. `insert into table ....`

Comment: i know but where can I do the insertion process? Is the stored procedure in database or web method in java?

Comment: You seriously need to google "the Single Responsibility Principle". Putting database stuiff directly into your webservice is bad, just bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@WebMethod
        public String add_ilce (int yourInput) {

            Statement stmt=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Connection conn=null;
            String deger=null;

            try {
              conn= getConnection_test();
              String query = "INSERT INTO DUAL" + "(yourAttributeName)" +"VALUES (?)";
                  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStmt.setString (1, yourInput);
                preparedStmt.execute();



            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "hata";
            } finally {
              try {
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                return "hata";
              }          
            }            
            return deger;
        }
```

EDIT: I suggest you to use DAO approach for such scenarios, check here: [Data access object (DAO) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154202/data-access-object-dao-in-java)

EDIT: I edited the post now it must work as it should be, sorry I had some mistakes

Comment: web service didnt appear on localhost, there are others.

Comment: thanks @imoteb  , it successful in this way                                      "INSERT INTO" +  " " + "table_name(AttributeName)" +" VALUES (?)"

Answer (score 0):

web service didnt appear on localhost, there are others.

```
@WebMethod
    public String add_ilce (String p_no, int p_tplm) {

        Statement stmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Connection conn=null;
        String deger=null;

        try {
          conn= getConnection_test();
          String query = "INSERT INTO DUAL" + "TEMP_TAHAKKUK_AG(ABONENO,TOPLAM)" +"VALUES ('p_no','p_tplm')";
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

          while (rs.next()) {
              deger = rs.getString(1);                        
             }        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "hata";
        } finally {
          try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            return "hata";
          }          
        }            
        return deger;
    }
```