# Populate Java swing JComboBox with Oracle SQL resultSet

Tags: java, oracle, swing, class

I am working on a simple application that includes a JComboBox for users to select from. I am new to Java and am having trouble populating the JComboBox with results from an SQL select statement. This is due to my lack of knowledge!

I have written 3 classes, a dbConnection class to handle the db side of things. Another class that instantiates my GUI, and the last class contains my main method:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

// Extends java.sql :~ describes connections to Oracle db
class dbConn {

    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    String conString;
    String sqlString;

    void dbConn() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection established, database uplink is online.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection failed, please check database status.");
        }
    }
}
```

Second class for the GUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class CaseMoverUI {
    void testUI(){

        // Create a new JFrame container
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("CaseMover");
        jfrm.setSize(550, 450);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JComboBox jbox = new JComboBox();
        jfrm.add(jbox);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new CaseMoverUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And lastly:

```
public class sqlCaller {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //instantiate db object and pass values to the constructor
        dbConn db = new dbConn();
        db.conString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/password123@127.0.0.1:1521:xe";
        db.sqlString = "SELECT true FROM dual";

        db.dbConn();
        CaseMoverUI ui = new CaseMoverUI();
        ui.testUI();
    }
}
```

The first thing I am not sure how to do is to retrieve my results and add them to the JComboBox. I know I need to write a method for the dbConn class, and pass an SQL query to it.

Using the HR test schema with Oracle XE, SQL query might be something like:

```
SELECT first_name FROM employees;
```

I'm not sure of the proper way to write this method however. Any help here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to get a List of your result from database :

You need to return your connection to use it in other method like this :

```
public Connection dbConn() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection established, database uplink is online.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection failed, please check database status.");
        }
      return conn;
    }
```

Then your method to get the list of your employee :

```
public List<String> listeEmployee() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection con = dbConn();
    try {
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT first_name FROM employees";

        ResultSet resultat = stm.executeQuery(requete);
        while (resultat.next()) {
            list.add(resultat.getString("first_name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then you can add this results to your JComboBox like so :

```
//Empty your JComboBox
jbox.removeAllItems();
for (String employee : listeEmployee) {
    jbox.addItem(employee);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. The first code block needs a return value I think doesn't it? 

public Connection dbConn()

What do I need to return from this?

Comment: Sorry @JamesPy i forgot to set `return conn;` in the end i edit my answer now

Comment: Ah yes I see @YCF_L. 
There are errors in the employee method. 
type List does not take parameters -- lines 1 and 2.
Also >> ResultSet resultat = stm.executeQuery(requete); -- requete is wrong I think?

Comment: your Statement should be like this `Statement stm = con.createStatement();` not like the first one

Comment: Got it thanks! I am left with an error List<String> list = new ArrayList();
for line 2 of the listEmployee() method: 
List<String> list = new ArrayList(); Any ideas on this? I am not familiar with this syntax.

Comment: This return to you a List of Strings so make sure you call this your imports `import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133929/discussion-between-jamespy-and-ycf-l).

Answer (score 0):

A `ResultSet` object is a table of data representing a database result set, which is usually generated by executing a statement that queries the database.  For example, the `selectDataFromDatabase()` method creates a `ResultSet`, `rs`, when it executes the query through the `Statement` object, `stmt`. Note that a `ResultSet` object can be created through any object that implements the Statement interface, including PreparedStatement, CallableStatement, and RowSet.

You access the data in a `ResultSet` object through a cursor. Note that this cursor is not a database cursor. This cursor is a pointer that points to one row of data in the `ResultSet`. Initially, the cursor is positioned before the first row. The method `ResultSet.next` moves the cursor to the next row. This method returns `false` if the cursor is positioned after the last row. This method repeatedly calls the `ResultSet.next` method with a `while` loop to iterate through all the data in the `ResultSet`.

```
public Vector selectDataFromDatabase() {
        Vector vector = new Vector();
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT first_name FROM employees";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                 while (rs.next()) {
                     String firstName = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
                     vector.add(firstName);
                 }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured! I cannot find driver!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("An error has occured while closing database connection!");
            }
        }
        return vector;
    }
```

In your GUI:

```
Vector vector = selectDataFromDatabase();
JComboBox jbox = new JComboBox(vector);
```

Or just simply:

```
JComboBox jbox = new JComboBox(selectDataFromDatabase());
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this idea. This is similar to the code I wrote first time around. However as I add more queries to the application, I would need to write a new class like this for each query, is that correct? I was wondering if this is the best way of doing it, or whether I can write a more abstract class for handling connections and pass new SQL queries to it for different purposes.

Comment: If you're going to use only a few queries in your application I dont think you need more than a few methods for that. But If you are interested in a more abstract solution take a look at DAO pattern. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154202/data-access-object-dao-in-java)
Edit: [Oracle source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)

Comment: Thank you for your input here @Zsolt Ébel. I will research DAO for my next application!